# URLComponents fails on 'path' part

Tags: swift, mailgun, nsurlcomponents

What if `path` is more complex? How can I get URLComponenets get work is path is this?

```
urlComponents.path = "v3/sandbox115e22c785254f36953c9f28337689bb.mailgun.org/message"
```

unfortunatelly it fails here:

```
guard let uriString = urlComponents.url?.absoluteString else {
    return request.eventLoop.makeFailedFuture(Abort(.badRequest))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of `URLComponents` a path **must** start with a slash

```
urlComponents.path = "/v3/sandbox115e22c785254f36953c9f28337689bb.mailgun.org/message"
```